# keep the first line that matches a string search and remove all following lines that have the same string matched

Tags: sed, awk, perl, ksh, egrep

I am trying to keep the first line that matches a string search and remove all following lines that have the same string matched.

Any ideas?

```
$ cat example-input.txt
Question one|some other text
Question two|dfgdfgdfgvd
Question one| dfg dfg dfg dfg
Question three|aa bb cc dd eee
Question one|zz aa BB yy qq
Question four|zz xx yy qq

cat example-input.txt | someuniqprogramoroptions "Question one" > example-output.txt

$ cat example-output.txt
Question one|some other text
Question two|dfgdfgdfgvd
Question three|aa bb cc dd eee
Question four|zz xx yy qq
$
```

**UPDATE:** thanks for the awk code G-Man, you're the man!

```
$ cat example-input.txt | ./awk-firstlines-only.sh
Question one|some other text
Question two|dfgdfgdfgvd
Question three|aa bb cc dd eee
Question four|zz xx yy qq
```

Comment: Welcome to SU, mike! Can you show please what you are trying (code), we can't read your mind!

Comment: $ cat example-input.txt
Question one|some other text
Question two|dfgdfgdfgvd
Question one| dfg dfg dfg dfg
Question three|aa bb cc dd eee
Question one|zz aa BB yy qq
Question four|zz xx yy qq

cat example-input.txt | someuniqueprogramand >  example-output.txt

$ cat example-output.txt
Question one|some other text
Question two|dfgdfgdfgvd
Question three|aa bb cc dd eee
Question four|zz xx yy qq
$

Comment: Please do not respond in comments or by posting "answers" that aren't answers; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. Give as precise an explanation as you can.

Comment: thanks, sorry this is my first question post on here, and still trying to figure out how to use it - thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example you’ve given,
this `awk` command will produce the output you’re asking for:

```
awk '
    {
        i = index($0, "|")
        if (i == 0) {
                print "Error: line [" $0 "] does not have a \"|\" character."
        } else {
                prefix = substr($0, 1, i-1)
                if (++count[prefix] == 1) print
        }
    }'
```

The first two lines of code verify that each input line contains a `|`. 
The next extracts the string before the first `|` character
(e.g., “Question one”). 
`count` is an associative array
that we use to count how many times each prefix has appeared. 
If this is #1 (i.e., the 1st appearance), print the line;
otherwise, print nothing.

Comment: Or let defaults do most of the work: `awk -F'|' '!count[$1]++'`

Answer (score 0):

If the first part has a fixed length, an alternative light solution is the command `uniq` combined with `sort` :

```
cat example-input.txt | sort | uniq -W 13
```

This is not very appropriate for your example, as you have a variable length and your file will be reordered, but this can be handy for similar jobs when you don't want to write a script.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nle' /Question one/ and ($count++ or print) or print' example-input.txt
```

...on the input of OPs example will produce his output.

Comment: I believe OP was asking for more or less the exact opposite of this.

Comment: The question didn't specify what to do with non-matching line. However his example with input and output do.